# Why the quadrature formula is exact one not an approximation?

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, quadratics, interpolation, discrete-calculus

I am reading [this material](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~rn/centroid.pdf) on the algorithm of calculating the centroid of a polyhedron.

I am confused by the last step of the deduction:

> The three coordinates of the centroid can be obtained:
>
> $$c\cdot e_k =\dfrac{1}{V}\int_{\partial P}\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x\cdot e_k\right)^2\left(n\cdot e_k\right)=\dfrac{1}{2V}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}\int_{A_i}\left(x\cdot e_k\right)^2\left(n_i\cdot e_k\right), k=1,2,3$$
>
> It remains to compute that:
>
> $$\int_{A_i}\left(x\cdot e_k\right)^2\left(n_i\cdot e_k\right)=\dfrac{1}{6}{\hat n}\cdot e_k\left(\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\left(a_i+b_i\right)\cdot e_k\right]^2+\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\left(b_i+c_i\right)\cdot e_k\right]^2+\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\left(c_i+a_i\right)\cdot e_k\right]^2\right)$$
>   where we have observed that the integrand is a quadratic function on $A_i$, so that the standard midpoint sampling quadrature formula for triangles yields the integral **exactly**.

I am confused: why it is an **exact** solution due to quadratic integrand?

**Update**

Per the comments below, my thoughts and confusions:

1. if this is only a $1$-$D$ quadratic interpolation problem, then the formula should be like: $f(x)=a_1^2\cdot \tfrac{(x-b_1)(x-c_1)}{(a_1-b_1)(a_1-c_1)} +b_1^2\cdot \tfrac{(x-a_1)(x-c_1)}{(b_1-a_1)(b_1-c_1)}+ c_1^2\cdot \tfrac{(x-a_1)(x-b_1)}{(c_1-a_1)(c_1-b_1)}\equiv x^2$
2. for multiple dimensional interpolation cases, there will be quadratic form like:

$$Q(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,1)\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 q_{1,1} & q_{1,2} & q_{1,3} & q_{1,4} \\
 q_{2,1} & q_{2,2} & q_{2,3} & q_{2,4} \\
 q_{3,1} & q_{3,2} & q_{3,3} & q_{3,4} \\
 q_{4,1} & q_{4,2} & q_{4,3} & q_{4,4} \\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot (x,y,z,1)^T$$
where $q_{i,j}=q_{j,i}$. Then for 3-$D$ interpolation there should be $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3+1}n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^4n=10$ coefficients to be determined.

Either case to me seems unsolvable and does not lead to the conclusion desired.

What is wrong?

**update 2**

The area above and below the horizontal line passing through the function value of the midpoint cannot be cancelled out actually...

[image]

Mathematica code for reference:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Green, Thickness -> 0.0005, 
   Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], Blue, Line[{{0, 1/4}, {1, 1/4}}]}, 
 Filling -> 0.25, FillingStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.38]], 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.035], PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Italic, 
      Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"})]
```

Comment: the standard midpoint 'sampling' formula essentially does quadratic interpolation using those points and integrates *that*; if the integrand is actually quadratic, then it gives the exact integral

Comment: Does that mean two-dimensional quadratic interpolation over three points?  If so, three points are not enough to determine 6 coefficients and problem is undetermined. Would you please post it as an answer with more details?

Comment: @LCFactorization For each k, there will be three coefficients.

Comment: Then $3\times 3=9>6$ means over-determination? I would appreciate it very much should you post more detailed answer (step-by-step answer or step-by-step keywords/clues so that I can do the research work myself)

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular situation, but I suspect the confusion is the same basic issue as for 1D Gaussian quadrature. There $n$ points will (surprisingly) integrate polynomials to degree $2n-1$. The reason why this works is that integration has a "null space" of polynomials that integrate to zero. For example, a linear with the root exactly at the midpoint, a quadratic with area below and above exactly canceling out, and so forth. The integration rule can safely ignore these polynomials, so the number of relevant degrees of freedom is less than the order of the polynomial.

Comment: thanks. I add my comment into the **upate 2** edit.

Comment: In response to the edit: for quadratic functions in the null space, the roots are not at the midpoint, but rather shifted a bit. In particular, any scaled multiple of the quadratic function $(x+1/\sqrt{3})(x-1/\sqrt{3})$ integrate to zero on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: So this depends on the symmetry of the quadratic integrand about the midpoint of the integral region. The $x^2$ in the original problem does not necessarily have such a property.